# Shapefile attribute table to Datagridview with C#

Tags: arcobjects, c#

Can you please let me know how to display a shapefile attribute table in C# DataGridView?

Answer (score 1):

This is an excellent sample that shows how to bind a Table to a .NET control:

[Bind a geodatabase table to a .NET control](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#//000100000312000000)

You will have to edit it slightly, to use a shapefile instead.